# Linux Game Development - Dependency Management

Tags: linux, steam

I'm working on a game that I'm trying to build for Linux and distribute via Steam. At present, there are some dependency issues and I'm wondering about the best approach:

1. Bundling .so files with the executable (Is bundling legal/safe? The libraries in question are libopengl.so.0, libopenal.so.1, and libsteam_api.so which I'm less concerned about)
2. Including a shell script to check for/prompt installation of dependencies (I can apt install all the necessary dependencies, of course. But I want to be respectful and not force install of something without permission.)

Assuming that we're bundling one or more .so files, I'm unclear on whether LD_PRELOAD or LD_LIBRARY_PATH is the preferred approach to inform the executable about their presence. Which is preferable?

Comment: Do you think a user of a distribution which prefers `yum` or `packman` as a package manager would be happy about your script trying to run `apt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is bundling legal?

That depends on the license terms of the library. For example, the GPL says that if you use a GPL-licensed library then your whole game must be licensed under the GPL, while a LGPL-licensed library permits you to bundle your libraries with non-GPL software as long as they are dynamically linked.

Is bundling a good idea?

Yes. There are lots of good reasons for operating systems to manage libraries in a centralized manner. But gaming isn't one of them.

- Giving the user the ability to patch libraries system-wide independently from the applications which use them does not matter, because games are usually not run on high-security systems and usually don't act as public servers (game *servers* are of course another subject).
- Storage space does not matter, because games usually take gigabytes of storage anyway. A couple MB of redundant libraries is not going to matter.
- What does matter for games, though, is having a robust, idiot-proof setup which just works out-of-the-box without the user having to tinker with anything. Shipping your game with all its libraries included makes sure that [the game won't malfunction because the end-user happens to have a newer version of a library which happens to work just a slight bit different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell). Every possible point-of-failure of your game installation process means you are going to get a couple more negative reviews saying "Does not run - refunded". So you want to minimize them as much as you can.
- When you use Steam, you can't install system-wide libraries because you don't know which package manager is used by the Linux distribution the user is using. `apt` is not the only package manager. There are also `pacman`, `yum` and a lot more exotic options. You can't possibly write an install script which detects and supports them all. Technically Steam is also a package manager. But its ability to install system-wide libraries is limited to the list of "[Common Redistributables](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/common_redist)" provided by Valve. You *can* handle dependencies shared between Steam games using "[Shared Depots](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/application/depots)". But in order to share these dependencies, you need to have control over all the games making use of them. So if you plan to release a lot of games which all use the same versions of various libraries, you could *theoretically* turn those into a shared depot so players who install more than one of your games don't need to download your libraries twice. But I doubt it's worth the effort, because again, libraries are rarely the bulk of a game download. Shared depots are mostly intended for shared *assets*.